# Multiple definition of a symbol while building a shared library with static libraries

Tags: c, linux, unix, gcc, shared-libraries

I have to build a single shared library from multiple object files. Lets say object file `Obj1.o` and `Obj2.o` kept under obj_folder and both use a common function `foo()`. function `foo()` is defined in another cpp file lets call it foo.cpp. The ibject of foo.cpp is also present under obj_folder.

Scenario is as below:

```
In obj1.cpp
void func1()
{
int timestamp =foo();
}

in obj2.cpp
void func2()
{
int timestamp = foo();
}
```

Both files have their obj1.o and obj2.o build separately. What my thinking here is both obj1.o and obj2.o have statically build code for foo() and while in building linker just cant find from which object it should pick foo() location.

building shared object `project.so` i use following command -

```
gcc -shared -fPIC obj_folder/*.o -o project.so
```

building shared object i see error message -

```
Multiple definition of foo()
```

How i can resolve this symbol collision and build my shared librray?

Comment: Do Obj1 and Obj2 define their own copies of foo? If so you should only define one copy (in either obj1 or obj2 but NOT both), place a prototype for foo in a header using the `extern` keyword (and include it when needed).

Comment: you simply can't define 2 times the same function in one prog or lib. Do you really have defined it 2 times? Why?

Comment: I have edited my question a bit. I have given more light on my understanding of the situation.

Comment: Your question has no information about where/how `foo` is defined.

Comment: @R i have updated the question and added where foo is defined.

Comment: How many .o files are present in obj_folder? Any old ones that also include foo()? How are your obj1 and obj2 modules made aware of the declaration of foo()? (You're not #include-ing .cpp files, are you?)

Comment: I am not #including cpp files. I am just curious why linker gives 'multiple definition of foo()' as error msg. This error msg comes for the file where foo() has been defined means foo.cpp. If i remove obj1.o and obj2.o objects this error goes away.

Comment: The "static" is only in your description, but is missing in the code example. That seems to be your problem. Two symbols with global visibility are conflicting.

Answer (score -1):

> Multiple definition of foo()
>   How i can resolve this symbol collision and build my shared librray?

Unfortunately you have not provided enough info to answer that question.

Your description appears to imply that `foo` is defined in `foo.o`, but if that was so, you wouldn't get the link error you are getting.

The first step is therefore to find out where `foo` is *actually* defined. Here is the recipe to do so:

```
nm -A obj_folder/*.o | grep ' foo$'
```

For the link error to make sense, there should be two separate `.o` files with `foo` defined in each one. When linking you library, you'll have to get rid of one of them.

P.S. Don't call *directories* a "folder".

P.P.S. Linking a library like so: `gcc ... obj_folder/*.o -o project.so` is a really bad idea(TM). Learn and use `make`.

Comment: @Emploed Russian can you please link some tutorials on how to prepare a dynamic library? Btw make is just one tool that I know quite well, but missing the guide about shared libraries. I hit this issue with header only library which was included in two cc files (object files)